# How to conditionally select JavaScript in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html, angular-dart-routing

The instruction for routing in AngularDart recommend the following for development mode, but explicitly says not to use it for production:

```
// WARNING: DO NOT set the <base href> like this in production!
// Details: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router
(function () {
  var m = document.location.pathname.match(/^(\/[-\w]+)+\/web($|\/)/);
  document.write('<base href="' + (m ? m[0] : '/') + '" />');
}());
```

How can I conditionally include this code in development mode, only?  I believe I know how to detect development mode in Dart code, but I'm not sure how to detect the mode and make the selection in JavaScript before any of the application code even loads.

Comment: Can't find the code you posted above in https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router

Comment: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router/1#set-the-base-href

Comment: How did you get to this `.../1` link? From https://webdev.dartlang.org/version there is no link to that URL.

Comment: Go to that link, place your cursor on the "Set the base href" title, and then click the link icon that appears to the left of it.  But the question remains, regardless of where this link came from...

Comment: I'd use a build script that copies a different `index.html` in place before `webdev build`

Comment: You could check if just setting it for Angular works for you as well https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/3e401548a47581112e60dabcdd37be418cbbff5d/doc/effective/dependency-injection.md#do-use-the-fortoken-constructor-for-tokens which can be done easily depending on release/debug mode.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a guide to select different index.html files at build time?

Comment: No, don't think there is. Just use a batch script to copy files